# Support for OMX interface in Android StageFright software codecs

Tags: android, codec, stagefright, openmax

Do Android software codecs (for example `OMX.PV.mpeg4enc`) support OpenMAX (OMX) interface? For example, do they support standard OMX functions like `OMX_FillThisBuffer`, `OMX_EmptyThisBuffer` etc? Or only hardware decoder support OMX interface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `OMX.PV.mpeg4enc` is an openmax component. But its no longer used in android.

This is a software codec, provided by packet video company. Only chipset vendors like TI, Qualcomm provide hardware codecs as OpenMAX IL components.

So yes, both software and hardware codecs support (and should support) OMX interface in order to be used by the media framework on Android.

Answer (score 0):

OMX.PV.mpeg4enc is an software codec .openmax component means that an wrapper of multimedia's functions . In my understanding ,its roles likes decodec or encodec .
From a certain point of view, it can be understood as codec,so it support omx.